# How to generate email, with image, from HTML template

Tags: c#, html, image, email, outlook

I am trying to generate Outlook emails from HTML templates, changing certain values in the email.

If there are images in the HTML template, they work and then stop working, displaying the 'red cross' instead. They usually stop working the following day after making the HTML template.

I am using Outlook to make the HTML templates in the first place, and can't really avoid this.

Here is my code:

```
private void generateEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String firstDate = formatDate(dtFirstDate.Value);
        String secondDate = formatDate(dtSecondDate.Value);
        String dateOne = formatDate(dtDate1.Value);
        String dateTwo = formatDate(dtDate2.Value);
        String dateThree = formatDate(dtDate3.Value);

        string strHTML = "";
        string subjectPrefix = "";

       try
          {
          strHTML = File.ReadAllText(templateLocation + "/PRF_Request.htm");
          subjectPrefix = "PRF - ";
          }
       catch
          {
          MessageBox.Show("Template Not Found");
          return;
          } 

        /*
         * Replace Placeholder Tags in the HTML with data.
         */
        string email = strHTML
            .Replace("�", " ")
            //.Replace("##Name##", user)
            .Replace("##application##", tAppName.Text + " (" + tVendor.Text + ") " + tVersion.Text)
            .Replace("##FirstDate##", firstDate)
            .Replace("##SecondDate##", secondDate)
            .Replace("##date1##", dateOne)
            .Replace("##date2##", dateTwo)
            .Replace("##date3##", dateThree);


        if (rbOutlook.Checked)
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application objOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)(objOutlook.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attatchment colAttach = new Attachments;

            // Assigns the default email attributes
            oMail.To = "";
            oMail.CC = "";
            oMail.BCC = "";

            oMail.Subject = subjectPrefix + tAppName.Text + " (" + tVendor.Text + ") " + tVersion.Text + " - " + tAppID.Text;

            if (bImportance.Checked){

                oMail.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;

            }else{
                oMail.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
            }

            // Define the Mail Message Body.
            oMail.HTMLBody = email;
            oMail.Display();

        }
        else if (rbLotus.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Generate Lotus Notes Email");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a relative or absolute image link?

Comment: @John - The HTML generated by Outlook is unfathomable, there is a lot going on I don't understand, but the image source is relative. It seems to work most of the time, but then breaks (seemingly) randomly.

Comment: Your image links need to be absolute and hosted online. EG:  `src="http://www.yourSite.com/path/myImage.png"` NOT `src="images/myImage.png"`

Comment: The HTML is awful because Outlook uses Word as a rendering engine. The images would have to be attached to the email and referenced by the HTML, possibly by using cid. What are you actually trying to achieve? Have you considered just using MimeKit to generate an .eml instead? Any mail client can open these, as they are just MIME.